# Hadoop 2.7.7,can not open resource manager web with port 8088

Tags: hadoop

i'm trying to learning hadoop, and i finished it with one namenode and two datanode, but i can't open resource manager web in browser.

in namenode:

```
[root@hadoop1 hadoop]# netstat -tupnl | grep java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.5:9000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8518/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9693/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8518/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8088          :::*                    LISTEN      11318/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8030          :::*                    LISTEN      11318/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8031          :::*                    LISTEN      11318/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8032          :::*                    LISTEN      11318/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8033          :::*                    LISTEN      11318/java

[root@hadoop1 hadoop]# jps
12114 Jps
8518 NameNode
11318 ResourceManager
9693 SecondaryNameNode
```

and i can open http://192.168.1.5:50070, is the reason for tcp6? 
how can i resolve it? thanks.

Comment: if you need any config or others,please let me known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my yarn-site.xml

add this:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>192.168.1.5:8088</value>
</property>
```

then execute this:

```
yarn-stop.sh
yarn-start.sh
```